# Why do application folders contain so many files?

Tags: file, compilation, notepad++, exe

I have a general question about finished applications. When I go into the files of a windows computer application, some files make sense as to why they are there, such as the executable, various media files, .dll files, etc. However, what I don't understand is how there's potentially thousands of different files, located in hundreds of different directories (counting hierarchy) with anywhere between dozens and hundreds of different filetypes. Some of the filetypes don't even seem like actual files, the extension could be something completely obscure. How does the application know how to work with that? Are all of those files hand-written and compiled or are many of them supplied automatically upon generating a desktop application (which would vary based on the application, of course)? I've never actually compiled an application in any language, as I've been studying JavaScript as a starting point, and I recognize that JavaScript is not intended for creating standalone applications, it's used to implement inside HTML. This is why I have so many questions about the generation of the application itself.

To provide an example, a few of the file extensions I see contained in the Audacity application folder which I don't recognize are as follows: *.lsp .raw .mo .ny .exp*

Even that is a very short list compared to the amount of filetypes/extensions I usually encounter which I have no knowledge of. So, all in all, my main question is why there's such a crazy amount of files, folders, and filetypes/extensions being used by an application. Hopefully someone can help me understand.

---

Extra question, for those who might care to answer it:

What does it mean when you open a file in an application like Notepad++ (or a .plist editor) and it's just a bunch of unreadable characters? I'm assuming that means it's a compiled file, but I could use some clarification. This happens when I try to open an .exe, a .dll, etc. I understand why I can't edit things like that in a text editor of course, yet why all the strange symbols and characters? Why wouldn't it just throw an error upon trying to open it? Are all the strange characters just a way of attempting to interpret already compiled code?

Bear with me, I'm pretty new to programming and I'm trying to get a better understanding of the process behind actually generating a GUI-based desktop application. As I said before, my current knowledge doesn't extend to the point of actually compiling an application.

Thank you for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Most of such "strange" files are resources needed by parts of the application. A complex application is constructed very modular, and each component may need to load different additional resources, often depending on conditions decided at runtime.

For example, on startup if a Qt-based application reads it should use German translation, it may load trans/de_DE.qm from a directory also containing other language files. Or a game may load level by level from different files depending on how far you've come.

---

Your second question is quite simple. Most resource files are read by an application function as stream of bytes. If e.g. such stream contains '005a' as 4 bytes, you'll see strange symbols in notepade.exe since that editor interprets such bytes as ASCII code, which means it prints the symbols it finds at place 0, 0, 5, and a in the ASCII table. But the application actually reads it in as 4 x 8 bits = 32bit value, which may mean a 32bit integer value of a variable in my simple example. So the variable value is set to 0x5a wich is decimal 90.

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on your extra question: you have to learn what a binary file and a text file is, but in short: Imagine you have a simple calculator program that stores the result in a file. Lets say the result you want to store is the number 64. You have to options to do it: saving it as text (characteres 6 and 4) or as a binary data.

If you store it as a text, you need two bytes: one for the code of the character 6 and other for the character 4. You can open that file with the notepad and you'll see that two characteres '64'.
If you store it as a binary value, you only need one byte, but if you open it with the notepad, you'll see the character whose code is 64: 'A'